# Google Maps Photo not showing pictures

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, retrofit, android-glide

I am trying to get photo's from restaurants in my city.

This is the result set from one of the restaurants.

```
{
     "formatted_address" : "Oranjesingel 2C, 6511 NS Nijmegen, Netherlands",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 51.8422931,
           "lng" : 5.8626707
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 51.8435754802915,
              "lng" : 5.864029830291503
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 51.8408775197085,
              "lng" : 5.861331869708498
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "8ccec67db5bcfdf6d1834c5a7ef3e23a20ca10e1",
     "name" : "MANNA Nijmegen",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true,
        "weekday_text" : []
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 1182,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113695304522183603442/photos\"\u003eMANNA Nijmegen\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA8FoXKUNAFzfqC0eLyW9bif0NkwG68fX6RYOMsS_LHljLMQburGeS5ZdepIz48zPthQA4r1DLwFd8bcSOsgdylYdREY-ba8I0VZvh0_m1BCX-vFNh3LtN61Y9HCX9lCVjEhBXj67s7Qb_OLnlNd6TrvFfGhT47VdxeE8zFKbYkqge9IlC5jtepg",
           "width" : 2660
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJAeG2ZlsIx0cRP0JpZPZNGr0",
     "rating" : 4.4,
     "reference" : "CmRSAAAAraBcK51UuB6Sh4HWKIth4_dqJJyrX6MCqoNhocN7DnbIdqqjMZvRsXM088hfFOUC2inrnNJRiIq4EWDVQtfP7b7QlcFWzMVysKQvPlalo6GiqRdMTcXAPA4pmmui0xQfEhDm3DzwNDvh9zBpDnf518VsGhQsBn6svBocV4VdzNyosm3dYf-CAA",
     "types" : [
        "restaurant",
        "bar",
        "lodging",
        "food",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
     ]
  }
```

Like you can see there is a `photo_reference`. When I go ahead and try to insert this `photo_reference` into this link:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=PHOTO_REFERENCE&key=KEY`

it will give me the `403` picture. I have verified that my key is working by checking it with this link, that is located on the Google Maps API website.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I have also tried different photo references from other restaurants out of my result set. What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you display how you get photos in your code, please? It will be better in order to help you.

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X I am developing in Java with the Android SDK. I am using Retrofit the get the JSON, then I am using Glide to load the image from the Google API. The code is too much to paste on this site because there is too much side stuff in it. Also when I try to open the link in browser it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I open a link with photo_reference from your sample

`CmRaAAAA8FoXKUNAFzfqC0eLyW9bif0NkwG68fX6RYOMsS_LHljLMQburGeS5ZdepIz48zPthQA4r1DLwFd8bcSOsgdylYdREY-ba8I0VZvh0_m1BCX-vFNh3LtN61Y9HCX9lCVjEhBXj67s7Qb_OLnlNd6TrvFfGhT47VdxeE8zFKbYkqge9IlC5jtepg`

I see this

[image: Google Places API Web Service]

HTTP 302, then HTTP 200. Could that redirect by the problem?

Comment: That is weird.. I guess there might be a problem with my key which is weird, because I have just requested a new one so that shouldn't be a problem.